# keyboard skips keystrokes with safetype keyboard (gnome/xfce)

Tags: keyboard

I have bought a new safetype keyboard (www.safetype.com). The problem is that during typing, I notice that certain keys are skipped (at random). This is not just that I miss something. Most commonly missed keys are when they are repeated. Some examples
are :
1. Down/up arrow keys.
2. Alt-tab to switch windows.

I searched for web and found in linux + ubuntu forums and found similar issues but none of the solution worked with me. (switch off/on Bounce keys etc).

I tried the keyboard on 2 different computers and found the same result. I tried on ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10.

However I tried it shortly on my laptop (on ubunut/windows) and didn't see the similar behaviour so my feeling is that keyboard is good but there is issue in either
a) usb driver
b) x window drive.

I don't see anything odd in "dmesg" or /var/log/messages. My keyboard is detected by kernel as :
[    3.556781] input: Plus More Enterprise LTD. USB-compliant keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/input/input2

I tried gnome/xfce and found the similar issue. I tried the console prompt but can't say for sure if issue exist there or not.

Motherboard of the PC : ASUS M4A785-M.

Questions I have is what should I do to diagnose the issue further. I have been using linux for more than a decade.

I noticed the similar bug e.g
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/34501
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/717970

But I don't think the issue is same.